# .NET/Oracle Document Management System

Tags: .net, oracle, document-management, dms

We have a custom built system that uses a ASP.Net front end with an Oracle backend (as per client requirements). Within this system is a custom module that functions as the system’s document management/content management system. The module allows us to (1) Upload and manage documents available on the website and (2) Edit HTML pages which provide the links to said documents.

We would very much like to do away with our custom module and replace it with 3rd party software – either open source or commercial. Keeping in the spirit of our ASP.Net/Oracle environment, does anyone know of existing software that would satisfy our needs AND uses a ASP.Net front end and Oracle database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some co-workers and I just started looking into an open source tool called "My Webpage Starter Kit." It has an ASP.Net front end (using the file based setup) and uses XML to store its data. It allows you to accomplish both of the requirements you mentioned above.

Here is the link: http://mywebpagesstarterkit.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ill have to give it a shot, but it seems lightweight and simple enough to try without to much effort. And the price is right

Answer (score 1):

The FileNet P8 Content Manager can store files in an Oracle database and it has a very rich API that you can use with .Net. It's not open source, and it's not cheap, but it can certainly do everything that you want to do and then some.

Also, please note that Oracle has a document management tool that is part of the "middleware fusion" suite of tools. It is also not free, but I know of a team that built a significant front-end on top of it using .Net.

HTH!

Tom Purl